# How to Export Multiple db folder in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu

I have db called Inventory, and different
collections- user,items, rate,batch,  etc
How to export db inventory and even import also

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to exporting your database, try `mongodump`.

```
mongodump --db Inventory --out <path to your backup directory>
```

To only export certain collections:

```
mongodump --db Inventory -c user --out <path to your backup directory>
mongodump --db Inventory -c item --out <path to your backup directory>
mongodump --db Inventory -c rate --out <path to your backup directory>
mongodump --db Inventory -c batch --out <path to your backup directory>
```

Note that exporting affects database performance.